# New into C#, null picturebox object in a picturebox array?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, null, picturebox

I'm just starting C#, and creating my first game, but just ran into a problem.
I have a picturebox array

```
PictureBox[] obstacles = new PictureBox[20];
```

And I'm trying to declare 20 new random location pictureboxes inside it.

```
    private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        player.Location = new Point(20, 240);
        player.Image = Properties.Resources.playerImg;
        Controls.Add(player);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            obstacles[i] = new PictureBox();
            obstacles[i].Size = new Size(10, 10);
            obstacles[i].Location = new Point(50, 340);
            obstacles[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            Controls.Add(obstacles[i]);
        }
    }
```

I know it's not spawning them into a random location yet, but I won't do that 'till I get them to spawn at all.
Now when I try to create a method to use picturebox array, it's objects (picturebox[0-19]) are all just null?

```
private void JustAnOtherTest(PictureBox obj)
{
    for (int y = obj.Top; y < obj.Top + obj.Height - 1; y++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Testing out!", "Test");
    }
}
```

Now calling: JustAnOtherTest(obstacles[1]); and adding a watch for obj in JustAnOtherTest method will just give me a null, why is that?

EDIT: Seems like it never goes into the for loop, cause it exits Game_Load once it gets to player.Image = Properties.Resources.playerImg; which probably means that the problem is in the resource files... :S

EDIT2: Yeah, I was right, the problem was within resource files. I had messed up with some namespaces and it couldn't find the resource file cause it was in a different namespace, but I ain't so sure why it didn't give an error on that. How ever, after fixing all the namespaces, works just fine. :)

Comment: Sounds odd to me, unless Game_Load hasn't actually been called...

Comment: Have you stuck a break point in your loop? (Click on it and press F9) Is Game_Load() even being called? What is the content of obstacles[i] directly after the new PictureBox() line?

Comment: is `Game_Load` called at all or at least before you are accessing `obstacles[2]`? The code that is posted looks quite alright.

Comment: Seems like once it gets to Controls.Add(player); it instantly jumps out of the Game_Load method, never arriving into the for loop, what the...?

Comment: Oh and yeah, player is also a PictureBox object, which works just fine. EDIT: No wait, seems like it jumps out of the Game_Load right BEFORE Controls.Add(player); Could it be that the resource file is incorrect?

Comment: How is player declared/initiated? Are there any exceptions thrown in Controls.Add(player)?

Comment: private PictureBox player = new PictureBox(); and no exceptions are thrown, but I guess the problem is actually in the resource file... Weird, it worked just fine earlier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibilities

1) Game_Load() is not being called before you access the array. Stick a break point in it and see if it fires.

2) You are somehow creating two variables called obstacles. Where is it defined exactly?

3) Something is clearing it again before you access it.

The most basic check is to put a breakpoint in your create loop, and check that the new is working ok at that point.

Comment: Or 4) Resource access is throwing an exception. ;D